# Integrated webcam is not working

Tags: webcam

when i trying to open my webcam through any app like google meet, cheese it is showing nothing but only dark screen.

When i checked by using ls usb cmnd following are the outputs. Please help to identify and resolve my webcam issue:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00be Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b6d9 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: It's this one: `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b6d9 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd `

Answer (score 1):

Had the same situation with my thinkbook S3. After several hours of googling, I detected a physical slider up to the camera.

Comment: same issue for beginners with T540p